# Layout don't moves up when soft keyboard shown

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

With this code in my `activityLayout`, layouts don't moves up when keyboard is open:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

When I delete this code, everything works fine and layouts move up. But I need to have this code in the activity.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this in your manifest file:

```
<activity name="YourActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize">
    ...
</activity>
```

Add this to layout file

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

Comment: I put this before but its not work when I add that code in my activity class

Comment: Ok, why do you need to set the flags?

Comment: I add this flag cause I want to set a custom background(not color) for status bar. And NavigationDrawer don't be under status bar background

Comment: Are you sure that you need to set flag? because status bar color can be set without it I presume